# How does this permutation algorithm work

Tags: prolog

```
ar([],[]).
ar([p(_,_)|L],L1):-ar(L,L2),L1=L2.
ar([p(X,Y)|L],L1):-ar(L,L2),L1=[p(X,Y)|L2].
```

(p stands for point, having the coordinates X and Y)

Please help me to understand how the result is being constructed, especially the part where L1 gets a new value, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your predicate `ar/2` behaves like the [powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) function, being a syntactic variant of the following (where `X` is restricted to terms of `p/2`):

```
% clause 1: base case
ps([], []).

% clause 2: omit the element X
ps([_X|Y], Z) :-
    ps(Y, Z). 

% clause 3: keep the element X
ps([X|Y], [X|Z]) :-
    ps(Y, Z).
```

The predicates `ps/2` (and your `ar/2`) basically backtrack to bind all sub-lists of the list in the first argument to that of the second argument. It achieves this with the choice represented by the second and third clauses: either omit or keep a list element when constructing the new list.

Consider what Prolog does when executing the goal `ps([a,b],L)`:

- `ps([_|[b]], Z) :- ps([b], Z).` (via clause 2, drop `a`).

  - `ps([b|[]], Z) :- ps([], Z).` (via clause 2, drop `b`; note that `[b]` = `[b|[]]`).

    - `ps([], Z)` binds `Z = []` (via clause 1, gives solution 1).
  - `ps([b|[]], [b|Z]) :- ps([], Z).` (via clause 3, keep `b`).

    - `ps([], Z)` binds `Z = []` (via clause 1, gives solution 2).
- `ps([_|[b]], [a|Z]) :- ps([b], Z).` (via clause 3, keep `a`).

  - `ps([b|[]], Z) :- ps([], Z).` (via clause 2, drop `b`).

    - `ps([], Z)` binds `Z = []` (via clause 1, gives solution 3).
  - `ps([b|[]], [b|Z]) :- ps([], Z).` (via clause 3, keep `b`).

    - `ps([], Z)` binds `Z = []` (via clause 1, gives solution 4).

Each of the deepest levels which hit the 'base-case' of clause 1 return up the call stack. Each of these cases result in the following:

1. Drop both `a` and `b`: `[]`
2. Drop `a`, keep `b`: `[b]`
3. Keep `a`, drop `b`: `[a]`
4. Keep both `a` and `b`: `[a,b]`

Thus, we can backtrack to generate `[]`, `[b]`, `[a]` and `[a,b]`, i.e., the four sub-lists of `[a,b]`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Good job on explaining clearly and concisely!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that this procedure does not compute a permutation, but a sort of sublist: a list with "some" points removed, where by "some" is said in general form (one of the solutions is the empty list and also other solution is the original list), assuming the input list is well formed.

If the input list is not well formed (it has one item which is not a "point") then the procedure will fail.

Now let's explain the three clauses of `ar/2`, which is a recursive procedure:

First clause,

```
ar([], []).
```

states that if the first argument is the empty list, then the second argument is also the input list; i.e. for an empty list the only "sublist" conforming with the rules of the procedure is also an empty list.
This is also the base case of the recursive procedure.

The second clause,

```
ar([p(_,_)|L], L1):-ar(L, L2), L1=L2.
```

can be rewritten without using the `L2` variable because it will eventually unify with `L1`:

```
ar([p(_,_)|L], L1):-ar(L, L1).
```

This clause is skipping the head of the input list and continuing with recursion. Upon return of recursion it will unify the resulting list (second argument of `ar/2` call) with the second argument of the head of the clause.

The third clause,

```
ar([p(X,Y)|L], L1):-ar(L, L2), L1=[p(X,Y)|L2].
```

can be, again, rewritten without using the `L2` variable by means of building the resulting list in the head of the clause:

```
ar([p(X,Y)|L], [p(X,Y)|L1]):-ar(L,L1).
```

This clause will take the head of the input list, continue recursion with the tail and then unify second argument of the head of the clause with the item taken and the resulting list of the recursion. That is, it will keep the item (head) of the input list along with the result of recursion.

Also note that this procedure is not reversible, if called with the first argument uninstantiated and the second argument instantiated it will loop forever.

Comment: i'm glad you pointed out that those clauses can be rewritten to that more readable form, thank you! however I had difficulty to see clearly how all the solutions are being generated, sorry for not making it explicit in my question